# How to mock withCriteria in grails 2.2.4 unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, grails-orm

The statement given below works well in grails 1.3.7 but fails in 2.2.4.
Mocking is not getting invoked.

```
YourDomainClass.metaClass.static.findFooBar = { -> [a,b,c]}
```

Gives this exception

```
|  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
        YourDomainClass.withCriteria() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

have you switched your unit tests to new API? in grails 1.3 you'd use ...UnitTestCase superclass for your test cases, in grails 2.x unit testing mechanisms changed, and now you should use `@TestFor(YourDomainClass)` or `@Mock(YourDomainClass)` on your test case class and no inheritence

Comment: not sure if this will fix the issue but I changed YourDomainClass.metaClass.static.findFooBar = {critera -> [a,b,c]}    to   YourDomainClass.metaClass.static.findFooBar = {Closure cls -> [a,b,c]} .......... Don't know what the reason is but exception suggests  Possible solutions: withCriteria(groovy.lang.Closure), withCriteria(java.util.Map, groovy.lang.Closure), createCriteria()